# Is 'ward' a form of 'werden' in this sentence?

Tags: conjugation, passive

Reading a book (written in  the 19th century), I came upon this sentence:

> Es ward gar nicht mehr gesprochen.

The form *ward* is unfamiliar to me, so I tried looking it up. I suspect it of being a form of *werden*, but it doesn't appear in the conjugation tables for *werden*. What is it then? Some archaic variant? Is there any difference in meaning as compared to "Es wurde gar nicht mehr gesprochen"?

Comment: Ich habe das Wort "ward" in eine Geschichte von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm, "Das Fürchten zu Lernen" gelesen. Die Küsterfrau in der Grimm Geschichte sagte, "Da ward ihr endlich angst, sie weckte den Jungen und fragte: 'Weißt du nicht, wo mein Mann geblieben ist? Er ist vor dir auf den Turm gestiegen.'" -- Interessiert aber veraltet. Ich liebe diese Sprache, aber ich habe noch viel zu lernen.

Comment: Related newer question: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/warum-wurde-und-nicht-ward

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're right. It's an archaic variant of *werden* in the first and third person singular indicative preterite.

As some people seem to confuse *wart* (form of *to be*) with *ward*, you find some information on [korrekturen.de](https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/ward.shtml):

> [...] Die Form ward gibt es aber auch; es ist die ursprüngliche, heute seltene Form der 1. und 3. Person Singular Indikativ Präteritum von werden: ich ward; er, sie, es ward. Heute sagt man stattdessen: ich wurde; er, sie, es wurde. Die alte Form ist in der literarischen und gehobenen Sprache noch üblich, zum Beispiel:
>
> > „Geblendet ward sie von der Laster Glanz / Und fortgeführt vom Strome des Verderbens. / Ihr ward der Schönheit eitles Gut zuteil …“ (Friedrich Schiller, „Maria Stuart“).

Its use converges to 0; there's just a little number of occurrences in corpora of contemporary German. And for such a common verb this little number speaks for itself. I think in that case an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=es%20ward,es%20wurde&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ces%20ward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ces%20wurde%3B%2Cc0t1;,es%20ward;,c0;.t1;,es%20wurde;,c0) is also quite self-explanatory.

Another source to second the quote above is [Fragen Sie Dr. Bopp!](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2008/12/12/und-es-ward-licht/), a Q&A site of canoo.net, which also points out that the second person is *wardst*.

Comment: +1 for Schiller ;)

Comment: Und es ward Licht.

Comment: Ich habe mal geschaut, in der Luther-Bibel ist es noch ausschließlich „ward“.