# Warum "wurde" und nicht "ward"?

Tags: etymology, history, conjugation, irregular-verb

Heutzutage ist der Präteritumstamm  von *werden*  ***wurde***. Früher war es ***ward***.

Mir scheint, dass *ward* die eigentlich regelmäßige Ablautfolge ist (vgl. helfen, werfen).
Und doch ward es nicht mehr gesehen.

- Warum hat sich *wurde* durchgesetzt?
- Seit wann existiert *wurde*?
- Welche Verben haben das gleiche Ablautmuster wie *werden*?

Comment: Siehe die ausführlichen Erläuterungen zu Formen und Verbreitung im Grimmschen Wörterbuch: https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/werden#werden

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Das heutige Deutsch hat im Großen und Ganzen eine Stammform weniger als das Urgermanische und Althochdeutsche und auch z. B. als das moderne Isländische, das in dieser Hinsicht das ursprüngliche germanische Muster bewahrt (ich verwende es hier anstelle des Standardaltnordischen, das es genauso gut getan hätte).

Im Isländischen sehen wir beispielsweise immer noch das System *verða* (Infinitiv), *varð* (1./3. Sg. Prät.), *urðum* (1. Pl. Prät.) und *orðið* (Partizip Prät. im Neutrum). Wenn wir das Isländische betrachten, so gilt zu sagen, dass es ein ursprüngliches *v* vor *u* und *o* verliert, dass also die Formen *urðum* und *orðið* aus **vurðum* und **vorðit* (mit *t*) enstanden sind. Die Formen *urðum* und *orðið* gehen genau wie die deutschen Formen *wurde* und *(ge)worden* auf dieselbe *Ablaut*stufe zurück (die verschiedenen Vokale sind durch *Umlaut* zu erklären, der in seinem Ursprung auf das Germanische zurückgeht und somit einige Jahrtausende jünger ist als der Ablaut, der indogermanischen Ursprung hat); allerdings wären Formen wie *wurden* und *wurdet* ursprünglich nur im Plural des Präteritums zu erwarten, während *ward* und *wardst* Singularformen des Präteritums sind, genau wie im modernen Isländischen.

In der Entwicklung zum modernen Neuhochdeutschen (die in Bezug auf die 2. Person Singular im Westgermanischen noch einer besonderen Schwierigkeit unterlag) sind allerdings im Präteritum die Ablautstufen zusammengefallen. Im Falle von *finden* zum Beispiel hat sich im Präteritum die Singularablautstufe durchgesetzt, sodass es *ich fand* und *wir fanden* heißt, anstelle ursprünglich *ich fand*, *wir funden*, so auch im Isländischen *ég fann*, *við fundum* (der Konsonantwechsel im Isländischen spielt an dieser Stelle keine Rolle). Im Falle von *werden* ist die Entwicklung leicht unregelmäßig, und nicht nur deswegen, weil sich die Pluralform mit dem Stamm *wurd-* durchgesetzt hat, sondern auch, weil die Standardform *ich wurde* auf *-e* endet, was für starke Verben ungewöhnlich ist. Andere starke Verben haben Formen wie *ich fand*, *ich las*, *ich goss* oder *ich biss*, ohne Endung *-e*.

An dieser Stelle weiß ich nicht genau, wieso *werden* so einen besonderen Fall darstellt; aber ich vermute, es liegt daran, dass es als Hilfsverb für das Futur und das Passiv eine besondere Rolle spielt und somit auch viel mehr mit Modalverben verknüpft wird, die häufig ein reguläres schwaches Präteritum mit der Endung *-(t)e* aufweisen.

Um deine Frage zu beantworten, welche Verben dasselbe Ablautmuster haben wie *werden*, so ist zu sagen, dass es einige sind, die das Muster ursprünglich hatten, z. B. *helfen*, *gelten*, *finden*, *binden*. Sie alle gehören der germanischen Ablautklasse III an.

Im 16. Jh. hatte Luther immer noch die alten Ablautverhältnisse, z. B. *fand* mit *a* im Präteritum Singular, aber *funden* mit *u* im Präteritum Plural. Dasselbe gilt für Luther in Bezug auf das Verb *werden*. Er hat *ward* im Singular und *wurden* im Plural. Dies kannst du z. B. überprüfen, indem du dieses Textstück auf die entsprechenden Verbformen hin durchsuchst:

- [Lutherbibel: Matthäusevangelium](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Lutherbibel/Matth%C3%A4usevangelium_%281546%29)

Comment: Wow... diese Antwort ist deutlich fundierter als ich es mir je erhofft hätte. Danke :)