# Verschiedener Stamm(?) bei Konjunktiv - empfähle vs empföhle

Tags: subjunctive

"Einfaches" Beispiel:

> Ich empfehle, Du empfiehlst usw.

Im Konjunktiv Präteritum:

> [Ich empfähle/empföhle, Du empfählst/empfhählest/empföhlst/empföhlest](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/empfehlen:V:haben)

Ich glaube, die kurzen Formen sind nur Verkürzung der jeweils langen, doch warum kennt der Konjunktiv 2 mögliche Formen der Stammanpassung?

Kann man das etymologisch Erklären? Gibt es Unterschiede in der Verwendung der beiden Formen innerhalb des deutschsprachigen Raumes?

Gibt es vielleicht auch Unterschiede, wo die jeweiligen Formen verwendet werden können?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dieses Phänomen trifft auf viele starke Verben zu, beispielsweise: *befehlen*, *beginnen*, *gewinnen*, *helfen*, *schwimmen*.

*Empföhle* ist die ältere Variante, *empfähle* ist eine Neubildung im Neuhochdeutschen. Bis ins Mittelhochdeutschen wurde für Singular und Plural unterschiedlich das Präteritum gebildet (Zur Bildung siehe [*Ablaut*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablaut#Ablaute_bei_den_deutschen_Verben)). Mit *a* für Singular und *u* im Plural. Also *ich empfahl* und *wir empfuhlen*. Somit haben wir auch zwei unterschiedliche Bildungen für den Konjunktiv II, der ja aus der Vergangenheitsform gebildet wird.

Irgendwann entschied man sich, dass die Vergangenheitsform einheitlich gebildet wird. Und es setzte sich die Singularvariante durch. Seither ist die Herkunft verschleiert.

Bleibt die Frage zu klären, wie aus dem *u* ein *ö* und nicht *ü* wurde. Das liegt an der Lautverschiebung, wodurch sich das *u* im Laufe der Zeit zu einem *o* verschoben hat. So wurde beispielsweise aus althochdeutsch *sun(u)* übers mittelhochdeutsch *sun, son* das heutige Wort *Sohn*. (Stichwort: Senkung hoher (=geschlossener) Vokale)
Genau das passierte auch bei den meisten dieser Verben. Ausnahmen dazu sind *helfen*, *sterben* und *stehen*.

Quelle: [Konjunktiv im Deutschen: 
Bildung und Anwendung](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/konjunktiv.php)

Comment: Auch zum Ausgleich der unterschiedlichen Ablaute in Singular und Plural: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7989